# Баг с тегом select в javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

У меня есть следующий код:

```
function choiceFun() {
    if (document.getElementById("multiChoice").options[0].selected=true) {
        $('#img0').css('display', 'block');
        $('#img1').css('display', 'none');
        $('#img2').css('display', 'none');
    } else if (document.getElementById("multiChoice").options[1].selected=true) {
        $('#img1').css('display', 'block');
        $('#img0').css('display', 'none');
        $('#img2').css('display', 'none');
    } else if (document.getElementById("multiChoice").options[2].selected=true) {
        $('#img2').css('display', 'block');
        $('#img1').css('display', 'none');
        $('#img0').css('display', 'none');
    }
}
```

и

```
            <select name="multiChoice" id="multiChoice" onchange="choiceFun()">
                <option value="0">Рыбалка в Алматы</option>
                <option value="1">Охота в Алматы</option>
                <option value="2">Подводная рыбалка в Алматы</option>
            </select>
            <img src="img/rybalka.png" id="img0" class="choice-img" alt="">
            <img src="img/ohota.png" id="img1" class="choice-img" alt="">
            <img src="img/podvodnaya.png" id="img2" class="choice-img" alt="">
```

Почему-то при выборе на странице любого `option` , выбирается `value=0`, и срабатывает соотв. функция, при том, что без этой функции сам select работает корректно. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (document.getElementById("multiChoice").options[0].selected == true) { // ==, a нe =
```

или просто

```
if (document.getElementById("multiChoice").options[0].selected) {
```

Comment: Спасибо. Всё работает. А для чего тогда нужен просто знак = в js?

Comment: @EasyTactic кхм, кхм, для присваивания значений

Comment: то есть ТОЛЬКО для var?

Comment: @EasyTactic Ну почему? Вы же сами видели, как это работало. Скажем, Вам нужно принудительно выбрать первую опцию в `select`:  `document.getElementById("multiChoice").options[0].selected = true;`

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо большое.